# Facebook Graph API - groups - empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am calling user/groups API to get all groups where user is admin `GET /v3.3/me/groups`

Now I started getting empty array as response from FB graph API. I am aware of that since April 4, 2018 this API endpoint is returning empty array unless the calling app has gone through App Review.

But even I submitted App for review and get it approved I am still getting empty array as response:

[image]

I can't find anything else required for this endpoint to have it working. In the Graph API Reference there is no any required permission for this [endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/user/groups#Reading).

Please if anyone know what else is required to get this endpoint working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `groups_access_member_info` permission from the user.

Without that, I am getting empty data with a dev app in Graph APi Explorer, with it - I get my groups.

(There used to be a `user_groups` permission specifically to get access to the user’s groups they are member of, but that is gone now.)

Comment: Is there anywhere in documentation written that this permission is required to get user groups? I don't see it anywhere and for me dev app is working fine without it. As I see this permission is for:
-Allow apps to get content posted in their group with user details
-Help admins get aggregated insights about activity happening in their group

Comment: No, I did not found it documented anywhere. But since `user_groups` is gone, I’d assume it has to have been replaced with something else - because that you could access a user’s groups without any additional permissions, based on public_profile only, seems rather unlikely to me. And in my tests, `groups_access_member_info` seemed to make the difference.

Comment: Well it looks like it's enough to have any of permissions for groups. I require "publish_to_groups"  and my dev app is working with that one and without "groups_access_member_info". If I remove "publish_to_groups" perm than I am getting also empty array with dev app. But still I have the same permissions with my Live APP and it is not working.

Comment: Yeah, could be that `publish_to_groups` also works, I did not specifically check. _“But still I have the same permissions with my Live APP and it is not working.”_ - your screenshot above does not show either of those as approved in review though …?

Comment: Yes yes, I just noticed minutes ago that's this permission is revoked for my live APP. I just re-submitted it for review and will see. But can't find it currently, but I read ages ago somewhere in the documentation that in order to get "user_id/groups" API working you need any of the groups permission. "publish_to_groups " or "groups_access_member_info" or any other will work.
It's stupid that they don't have it written in the API endpoint documentation. I will update with result once permission is approved for live APP